# Not able to extend Laravel package model to add UUID's

Tags: php, laravel

I am using the `coderflex/laravel-ticket` to create tickets in my Laravel project .. One thing i am using throughout my projects is Laravel's UUID functionality which I would like to bring into this package, what I have tried to do is firstly change the migration from

```
Schema::create('tickets', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    //
});
```

to

```
Schema::create('tickets', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->uuid('id')->primary();
    //
});
```

Then i tried to extend the model and create my own that uses the `hasUuids` trait;

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasUuids;

class Ticket extends \Coderflex\LaravelTicket\Models\Ticket
{
    use HasUuids;
}
```

But when trying to run it, I encounter the following issue;

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'id' doesn't have a default value (Connection: mysql, SQL: insert into `tickets` (`title`, `priority`, `message`, `user_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Testing new ticket, low, asdsa s asd assd as das a das dasd ad as, 9a154da5-fdb8-43b3-8fa3-909681d7173c, 2023-09-08 08:49:50, 2023-09-08 08:49:50))
```

Comment: the model should `implements CanUseTickets` check here [docs](https://github.com/coderflexx/laravel-ticket#preparing-your-model).

Comment: @francisco ... My User model already does implement this

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a default value to your primary key column.

```
    Schema::create('tickets', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->uuid('id')->primary()->default(DB::raw('(UUID())'));   
    });
```

By default integer ids have an [automatically incrementing](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) default value.